# Apollo's reincarnated lover

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this story about 4-5 years ago about the Greek god Apollo having a lover who keeps getting reincarnated. Set in modern times.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome Cassi. Please take a read of our [story ID checklist](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you can add some details, also take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance.

Comment: check if it is on this list here, in literature section. Or web original if you read it online: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ReincarnationRomance

Comment: I'm not sure why this one's been closed. It's not great for detail, but there can't be that many possible matches...

Comment: @Valorum I [found](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17713997-apollo-s-gift) [two](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/49522017-apollo-me) in just the first page of goodreads results...

Comment: @DavidW The question asks about a story where Apollo's lover "keeps getting reincarnated". Does that happen in your story, or is she only reincarnated once? Not clear from the review you linked to. For that matter, was Cassandra the god's lover in the first place? Seems like a stretch.

Comment: @user14111 Neither description seems to negate the possibility that this is not the first reincarnation; I'd have to read the books to check.  The point about Cassandra is reasonable, but only applies to one of the stories (in the other it's a reincarnated priestess), but is also within the bounds of "acceptable error" in OP's memory.  I wasn't trying to be completely accurate, just pointing out that it's not _that_ an uncommon plot.